# Fade Gallery with Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, image-gallery

I'm pretty new to programming and I was trying out JavaScript. I found many posts about fade Galleries but no one with automatic Gallery but also buttons to change the image manually too.

```js
var myIndex = 0;
slider();

function slider() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("Galleryimg");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(slider, 9000);
}
```

```css
/* CSS is not relevant I think, but I post it anyway. */
.Galleryimg {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Gallery">
  <img class="Galleryimg" src="images/Header.png">
  <img class="Galleryimg" src="images/Header2.jpg">
  <img class="Galleryimg" src="images/Header3.jpg">
</div>
```

thats just a normal Gallery with changing images, any way to make that a fade gallery and add buttons to change the image manually? or do i have to rewrite the Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation setting `opacity` and `position` property. But remember while using this implementation the images must be of same sizes.
 So I set the `opacity` of all images to 0 and position of all images to `absolute` overlapping them one upon another and animated the fade using the transition property of css. Updating the opacity of the image to 1 letting it fade in.

```js
var myIndex = 0;

function slider() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("Galleryimg");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.opacity = 1;
  
}
document.getElementById("change").addEventListener("click",function(){
 slider();
});
setInterval(slider, 4000);
```

```css
/* CSS is not relevant I think, but I post it anyway. */
.Galleryimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 4s ease-in-out;
}
#img1{
 background: red;
 }
#img2{
 background: blue;
}
#img3{
 background: green;
 opacity: 1; 
}
#Gallery{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 600px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="Gallery">
  <img class="Galleryimg" src="images/Header.png" id="img1">
  <img class="Galleryimg" src="images/Header2.jpg" id="img2">
  <img class="Galleryimg" src="images/Header3.jpg" id="img3">
</div>
<input type="button" id="change" value="change"/>
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but why does it stop working when i try to put the button under the gallery? and when i click the button it changes image 2 times

Comment: The button stopped working because I set the `position` of the gallery images to be `absolute` thus the button was below the galley which is now fixed by introducing the height and width to the parent div of the gallery. It changes twice when you click the button because you triggered it once and the other is triggered by the setInterval function.

Comment: thank you very much, can you just tell me one more thing i really don't get why i have a scrollbar at the bottom of the browser now if i set the gallery to be width 100% doesn't that mean it uses the whole window and not more?

Comment: the vertical scrollbar is seen because it's dependent on `height` and not the width property and the `height` is set to 600px so if you set the height properties to somewhere below 100vh e.g. `height:100vh` where vh is the view height the scrollbar will not be seen.

Comment: sorry mavbe i didn't ask the question clear enough i meant a horizontal scrollbar but managed to solve it, it was because the gallery was set to absolute and so the standard margin from the body tag didn't apply i think. when i set that to 0 the scrollbar disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly easy task. Just add your previous and next arrows to position absolute and set the gallery to relative positioning. Add click handler to decrement or increment the current index.

```js
var gallery = document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0];
var images = gallery.getElementsByClassName("gallery-img");
var currentIndex = -1;
var timeoutMs = 3000;

gallery.getElementsByClassName('gallery-btn-prev')[0].addEventListener('click', prevSlide);
gallery.getElementsByClassName('gallery-btn-next')[0].addEventListener('click', nextSlide);

initializeAndRunSlider(gallery);

function initializeAndRunSlider(gallery) {
  nextSlide();
  setTimeout(initializeAndRunSlider.bind(null, gallery), timeoutMs);
}
function prevSlide(e) {
  currentIndex = mod(currentIndex - 1, images.length);
  displayCurrentImage();
}
function nextSlide(e) {
  currentIndex = mod(currentIndex + 1, images.length);
  displayCurrentImage();
}
function displayCurrentImage() {
  hideAllImages(images);
  showImage(images, currentIndex);
}
function hideAllImages(images) {
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    removeClass(images[i], 'visible');
    addClass(images[i], 'hidden');
  }
}
function showImage(images, index) {
  removeClass(images[index], 'hidden');
  addClass(images[index], 'visible');
}
function mod(m, n) {
  return (m + n) % n;
}
function addClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList) el.classList.add(className);
  else el.className += ' ' + className;
}
function removeClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList) el.classList.remove(className);
  else el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
}
function hasClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList) el.classList.contains(className);
  else new RegExp('(^| )' + className + '( |$)', 'gi').test(el.className);
}
```

```css
.gallery {
  position: relative;
}
.gallery-images {
  position: relative;
}
.gallery-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.gallery-controls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
.gallery-btn {
  font-size: 3em;
  opacity: 0.25;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.gallery-btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.gallery-btn-prev        { float: left; }
.gallery-btn-prev:before { content: "◄"; }
.gallery-btn-next        { float: right; }
.gallery-btn-next:before { content: "►"; }

/* https://fvsch.com/code/transition-fade/test5.html */
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 1s, opacity 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery-images">
    <img class="gallery-img visible" src="http://placehold.it/128x48/7ff/700?text=First">
    <img class="gallery-img" src="http://placehold.it/128x48/ff7/007?text=Second">
    <img class="gallery-img" src="http://placehold.it/128x48/f7f/070?text=Third">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-controls">
    <div class="gallery-btn gallery-btn-prev"></div>
    <div class="gallery-btn gallery-btn-next"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much but i decided to use acesmndr's answer in the end